# Complex xml validation

Tags: java, xml

I have a problem with validating xml file.
In my xml file the xsi:schemaLocation="" is poiting to the xsd file. Unfortunately this xsd file has loads of schema dependencies. They all point o some websites. Because of this the validation is failing. All tools and libraries fail, forex xmlSpy. When I point xsi:schemaLocation="" in xml file o local xsd (with all dependencies being local) validation works fine.

My question is relating to the javax.xml.validation can I tell it to ignore the xml xsi:schemaLocation="" inside my xml file or change it while doing validation. On production there will be hundreds of file to validated so I want to point the  xsi:schemaLocation="" to local xsd using avax.xml.validation without changing the xml file ?

Any ideas how to do it ?

Comment: A custom LSResourceResolver seems to be what you needed?
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/validation/Validator.html#setResourceResolver(org.w3c.dom.ls.LSResourceResolver)

Answer (score 1):

Create an implementation of [`LSResourceResolver`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/ls/LSResourceResolver.html), and make it the resolver for the [`SchemaFactory`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/xml/validation/SchemaFactory.html) used to load the `Schema`.

You can then load external XSD files from a local file store, to ensure that the files can be found.

It also improves performance.